# Enable java to support different languages while converting .txt file to .bmp(image)

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d, hindi

I am converting a .txt file to .bmp(image). That .txt file may have words of different languages as well. When I convert it using BufferedImage of java it converts the English words properly but not the other language's word, image shows the special character for the other language words. How can I enable my code to convert .txt file to .bmp(image) exactly ?

**My .txt File**

SBI Bank|स्टेट बँक ऑफ इंडिया
Date|तारीख
Time|वेळ
Demo|डेमो
Receipt|पावती
Total|एकूण
Amount|रक्कम
Deposited|जमा

** My Code**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TextToGraphics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int imgWid = 300;
            int imgHei = 300;

            String text = "Hello\nlklkj";
            String storeData = "";
            String data = "";
            File f = new File("/home/vipul/Desktop/123.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            int nextLinePosition=100;
            int fontSize = 24;
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
            g2d.setFont(font);

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int width =imgWid;
            int height =imgHei;
            g2d.dispose();

            img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            System.out.println(img.getWidth() + " " + img.getHeight());
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2d.setFont(font);
            fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 g2d.drawString(data, 0, nextLinePosition);

                nextLinePosition=nextLinePosition+fontSize;

            } 
            g2d.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", new File("/home/vipul/Desktop/123.bmp"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Is there any option that I can print the different language words in the image by making changes in the code or I have to enable any font support ?

Kindly advice.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the encoding of your text file? As your reading code does not specify an encoding, it will be using the system default encoding, which may not be the same as your file. And yes, you should also make sure the font you use have glyphs for the characters you use.

Answer (score 0):

You probably read your file with the wrong encoding.

Try to replace

```
        File f = new File("/home/vipul/Desktop/123.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

by

```
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/vipul/Desktop/123.txt"), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

(or whatever encoding is used instead of utf-8).

Comment: No This is not helping, sorry!!